# Search input file (.img) for a pattern (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whats the best way to take an input file (.img file) and search it for a pattern in python 3.

I've been using the .re module and tried reading the entire .img file in as a string ((file.read()) in both binary mode and in read-only mode, but I keep getting an error that it's too big for the buffer in Python. The file is relatively small (less than 5MB). Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Ultimately I want to take the .img file, run a pattern against it to search for a name, and return a statement as to whether the name was found in the file or not.

I don't want to use any 3rd party scripts. Any modules used should be already contained with python.

Comment: Just to confirm: is this `.img` file an image file, similar to bmp, png, gif? Or is it something else? When you're searching for a name, does that name appear as pixels in the shape of letters on a grid, or is it encoded in the file as ordinary ASCII data?

Comment: Yes, an .img file like a jpg. And the name would be ordinary in the ascii data in plaintext

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do some OCR type stuff, perhaps start by looking here:
https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/

Comment: Thank you apublius. But I guess I should have specified. I don't want to use any 3rd party modules. I want to be able to use this script on more than one computer and don't want to have to download an outside script for each computer.